# optimize array building from nested arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to optimize the extraction of a property's value from an array of objects, each object containing other nested arrays of objects, in Javascript.

I'm not really sure how to explain it by words, so here is some code to explain what I'm trying to optimize:

```
// test case
var first = [
    { second: [ { id:  1}, { id:  2}, { id:  3} ] },
    { second: [ { id:  4}, { id:  5}, { id:  6} ] },
    { second: [ { id:  7}, { id:  8}, { id:  9} ] },
    { second: [ { id: 10}, { id: 11}, { id: 12} ] }
];

// where the id values will be stored
var arrIDs = [];

// extracting the id values
for (var i=0; i<first.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<first[j].second.length; j++){
        // I want to avoid all these push() calls
        arrIDs.push(first[j].second[j].id);
    }
}
```

And this is the end result that I want to achieve:

```
arrIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

I may need that with up to 3 or 4 nested levels, but I may use a different structure to reduce it to 2 levels if it's not possible to optimize more than that.

What I would like to optimize the most is actually all those Array().push() calls inside the for loops.

Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

EDIT

I have forgot to mention that I would need to use this in an environment where IE8 is the best option we have. So ES6 is not an option.

Comment: please add how the 3rd or 4th level look like.

Comment: just the same as first-second level. Each second level would have a property containing an array, each field of the array being another object, and so on up to 4 levels deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this recursive ES6 function. It works for any level, and you can pass it an array, plain object, or anything else (in the latter case you get an empty array as result):

```js
function getAll(obj, key) {
    return obj !== Object(obj) ? [] 
        : Object.keys(obj).reduce ( (acc, k) => 
            acc.concat(k == key ? obj[k] : getAll(obj[k], key)), [] ); 
}

// sample data with different levels and mix of array / object alterations
var first = [
  { a: 2, id:  1}, { second: [ { id:  2}, { id:  3} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  4}, { id:  5}, { id:  6} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  7}, { third: {id:  6}}, { id:  9} ] },
  { second: [ { id: 10}, { id: 11}, { id: 12} ] }
];

var result = getAll(first, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For IE8 compatibility:

```js
function getAll(obj, key) {
    if (typeof obj != 'object' || obj == null) return [];
    var acc = [];
    for (var k in obj) {
        acc = acc.concat( k == key ? obj[k] : getAll(obj[k], key) );
    }
    return acc; 
}

// sample data with different levels and mix of array / object alterations
var first = [
  { a: 2, id:  1}, { second: [ { id:  2}, { id:  3} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  4}, { id:  5}, { id:  6} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  7}, { third: {id:  6}}, { id:  9} ] },
  { second: [ { id: 10}, { id: 11}, { id: 12} ] }
];

var result = getAll(first, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Looks pretty neat, but I need to use it in an environment where IE8 at most is available. ES6 is not available in IE < 9. But still a great solution :)

Comment: Ah, that is like important information. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: Added the note about ES6 in the question.
The compatibility version of your code looks quite nice as well. Thank you for taking time into this!

Answer (score 1):

For your data structure you can use `reduce()` and `map()`.

```js
var first = [
  { second: [ { id:  1}, { id:  2}, { id:  3} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  4}, { id:  5}, { id:  6} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  7}, { id:  6}, { id:  9} ] },
  { second: [ { id: 10}, { id: 11}, { id: 12} ] }
];

var result = first.reduce(function(r, o) {
  r = r.concat(o.second.map(function(e) {
    return e.id;
  }))
  return r;
}, []);
console.log(result)
```

ES6 version

```js
var first = [
  { second: [ { id:  1}, { id:  2}, { id:  3} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  4}, { id:  5}, { id:  6} ] },
  { second: [ { id:  7}, { id:  6}, { id:  9} ] },
  { second: [ { id: 10}, { id: 11}, { id: 12} ] }
];

var result = first.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(o.second.map(e => e.id)) , []);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: By looking at the solutions in the comments, benchmarking each, seems like this solution is the best. However, does it require ES6 ? The environment where I will be running it will have IE8 at most, and ES6 is not available...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a iterative and recursive proposal. This approach works for any level.

```js
function getValues(o, key) {
    return o !== null && typeof o === 'object' && Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r.concat(k === key ? o[k] : getValues(o[k], key));
    }, []) || [];
}

var first = [{ second: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] }, { second: [{ id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }] }, { second: [{ id: 7 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 9 }] }, { second: [{ id: 10 }, { id: 11 }, { id: 12 }] }];

console.log(getValues(first, 'id'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same as the for loops, just written differently? I mean, there are two forEach() calls which is just the shorthand for usual `for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)`

Comment: any of the methods for looping are some kind of for loop wit special feature, like just iterating, mapping, filtering, the use of quantizer or reducing. the question is only, which one would fit better.

Comment: You're right, the loops will be loops, no matter how you write them.